# Nativescript's AOT Compilation succeeds - but still the `Compiler` package included?

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, angular2-aot, nativescript-angular

I'm invoking :

```
npm run ns-bundle --android --build-app --uglify
```

It does succeed   (here is [*the complete log*](http://jsbin.com/cazecereco/edit?html)).

If I navigate to the `report` folder (*created by `webpack-bundle-size-analyzer`*) - I see those two files :

[image]

Opening the `html file` shows :

[image]

As you can see -  the compiler from @angular is still there !!!

**Question**

1)  Why does the compiler still there ? (AOT should remove it). How do I remove it ?
2) If I hover the bundle.js section it shows me parsed size. so what is stat/parsed size ?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/25bRez3.jpg]

---

**Additional info :**

I must say that when i search `bundle.js` in filesystem - I see two files :

[image]

And a second one :

[image]

---

**webpack.config.json** : http://jsbin.com/varetibaya/1/edit?html
**package.json** : http://jsbin.com/sajifojuki/edit?html
**main.aot.file** : http://jsbin.com/jimonurama/edit?html
**ts.config.aot** : http://jsbin.com/tatahesoma/edit?html

Comment: Looks like it's used somewhere. Try debugging your bundle. For example try to check if `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync`(or something other from jit compiler) is called

Comment: @yurzui -  [It does being called](https://i.imgur.com/6ThEc1t.jpg). so what does this mean ? that AOT is not working ? or is it ? I expect not to see `@compiler` in the graph

Comment: Or `JitCompilerFactory` is provided somewhere

Comment: Make sure that `platformNativeScript().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);` is starting point

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/nativescript-angular/platform.ts#L9-L12 Nativescript overrides these services But maybe it's only for dynamic platformNativeScriptDynamic. I haven't used it

Comment: @yurzui it is the starting point for the [main.aot.ts](https://i.imgur.com/H4fuU67.jpg) - not for the [main.ts](https://i.imgur.com/ZP7A34G.jpg) - IS that OK ?

Comment: Yes, that's ok. You should bootstrap module factory for aot

Comment: @yurzui I'm lost. I don't know how to remove  `@compiler` / verify that AOT works.

Comment: Did you try it with simple project? Maybe there is some boilerplate

Comment: it's their groceries demo app. even not my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@yurzui has found the problem .

Changed :

```
import {RouterExtensions} from "nativescript-angular";
```

with

```
import {RouterExtensions} from "nativescript-angular/router";
```

Now - there is no compiler in the package.

(With many thanks.).